# Remove gcloud VPC-SC security perimeter when no organisation is set up

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

A cloud run project that worked two months ago suddenly started complaining about the default log bucket being outside the VPC-SC perimeter. However, this project is not in an organisation, so I don't understand how I can remove the perimeter.

`gcloud builds submit --tag [tag]`

Errors with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit)
The build is running, and logs are being written to the default logs bucket.
Unfortunately, the default logs bucket is always outside any VPC-SC security
perimeter, so this tool cannot stream the logs for you.
```

While changing the controls is not possible:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your gcloud tools......

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the issue, I reviewed documentation according to your main question of how to remove gcloud [VPC-SC security perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/manage-service-perimeters#remove_a_service_from_the_vpc_accessible_services), and, if you activate VPC accessible services and then decide that the VPC networks in your perimeter no longer need access to the Cloud Storage service, you can remove services from your service perimeter's VPC accessible services using the following command:

```
gcloud access-context-manager perimeters update example_perimeter \
  --remove-vpc-allowed-services=example.storage.googleapis.com \
  --policy=example.11271009391
```

If the issue persists, you can leave a comment so that we can continue helping you, or here is a link that helps to [troubleshoot](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooting) any issue related to VPC Service Control.

Comment: The thing was that I couldn't change any settings, as the project wasn't in an organisation